# How do I get Liquid subtasks to display correctly?

Tags: liquid, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have been trying to figure this out for a few days and feel I must be missing something obvious. I am trying to pull the Subtasks out using Liquid in the RedmineUp Reporter Plugin.

The code I'm using is

```
{{issue.subtasks.all}}
```

and the output I get is

```
#<:liquid::issuedrop:0x0000557264852920>#<:liquid::issuedrop:0x00005572648528f8>
```

when as far as I can tell I should be getting the subtasks output. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to support, who indicated I was using the array improperly. Instead of the above code, the correct code is:

```
1.1.2.1  Subtasks <br />

{% for subtask in issue.subtasks.all %}

  {{ subtask.subject }} <br />

{% endfor %}
```